# Очистка экрана Python Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Как очистить окно приложения от всех виджетов(button, label и т.д.), слоёв (boxlayout, gridlayout)? Т.е. нужно получить пустое окно, куда потом будут добавляться уже другие виджеты из другого класса

Comment: А вы смотрели в сторону screenmager, screen? С ними можно создать несколько экранов. Если же такое не подойдёт, то можно, к примеру, взять главным виджетом сделать boxlayout, присвоить ему id и по этому айдишнику добавлять нужные вам элементы. А когда нужно заменить/обновить элементы, все так же по айдишнику обратиться к списку children boxlayout'а и либо обновить их каждый по очереди в цикле, либо удалить их.

Comment: солидарен насчет скрин менеджера, похоже это то, что надо

Answer (score 2):

Вот как это делаю я:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#-*-coding:utf-8-*-

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


#Загружаю разметку
Builder.load_string('''
<MainScreen>:
    orientation:'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba:(0.5,0.5,0.5,1)
            Rectangle:
                pos:self.pos
                size:self.size
        ScrollView:
            size_hint_y:None
            size_hint:(1,1)
            BoxLayout:
                id:another_box
                size_hint_y:None
                height:self.minimum_height
                orientation:'vertical'
                spacing:5
    BoxLayout:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba:(1,1,1,1)
            Rectangle:
                pos:self.pos
                size:self.size
        size_hint:(1,0.1)
        padding:5
        spacing:3
        Button:
            text:'create'
            on_release:root.create_widgets_in_another_box()
        Button:
            text:'recreate'
            on_release:root.recreate()
        Button:
            text:'update'
            on_release:root.my_update()
        Button:
            text:'clear'
            on_release:root.cleare_all_widgets_in_another_box()
        Button:
            text:'new screen'
            on_release:root.add_new_screen()


<MyNewScreen>:
    orientation:'vertical'
    Button:
        text:'Test Button'
    Label:
        text:'test Label'
''')


class MyNewScreen(BoxLayout):
    #Это мой новый экран
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


class MainScreen(BoxLayout):
    #Главный экран, на котором все будет происходить
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.num=1
        self.another_num=1
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def recreate(self):
        #удаляет все виджеты и создает новые виджеты
        self.cleare_all_widgets_in_another_box()
        self.create_widgets_in_another_box()
        self.num+=1

    def my_update(self):
        #проходит по списку всех детей виджета под именем another_box
        for child in self.ids.another_box.children:
            child.text="test update - {}".format(self.another_num*self.num)
            self.another_num+=1

    def create_widgets_in_another_box(self):
        #создает новые виджеты в виджете another_box
        for i in range(5):
            self.ids.another_box.add_widget(Label(text="Test create - {}".format(i+self.num),size_hint_y=None,height=100))

    def cleare_all_widgets_in_another_box(self):
        #удаляет все виджеты, которые находяться в another_box
        for i in range(len(self.ids.another_box.children)):
            self.ids.another_box.remove_widget(self.ids.another_box.children[-1])

    def add_new_screen(self):
        #удаляет все виджеты принадлежащие классу MainScreen и создает сделанный мной виджет MyNewScreen
        self.clear_widgets()
        self.add_widget(MyNewScreen())


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Но так обновлять экран не практично. Так можно удобно управлять внутренним наполнением виджетов, а с экранами лучше делать вот так:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button

Builder.load_string('''
<FirstScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba:(1,1,1,1)
            Rectangle:
                pos:self.pos
                size:self.size
        orientation:'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint:(1,0.8)
            Label:
                text:'This is first screen'
                color:(0,0,0,1)
            Label:
                text:'Push button "next"'
                color:(0,0,0,1)
        Button:
            text:'Next'
            size_hint:(1,0.2)
            on_press:root.manager.current='second'


<SecondScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba:(0,0,0,1)
            Rectangle:
                pos:self.pos
                size:self.size
        orientation:'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint:(1,0.8)
            Label:
                text:'This is second screen'
            Label:
                text:'Push button "previous"'
        Button:
            text:'Previous'
            size_hint:(1,0.2)
            on_press:root.previous_button()

''')


class FirstScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


class SecondScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def previous_button(self):
        self.manager.current='first'


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        #Добавляю красивый переход FadeTransition
        sm=ScreenManager(transition=FadeTransition())#Создаю менеджер экранов sm
        #обязательно нужно дать имя экрану, ведь по этому имени и будет производиться переключение
        #в kv файле для преключения нужно использовать root.manager.current, а в коде self.manager.current
        sm.add_widget(FirstScreen(name='first'))
        sm.add_widget(SecondScreen(name='second'))
        return sm

if __name__=="__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```